# Prediction of rainfall using nonhomogeneous Hidden Markov Model

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, knn, hidden-markov-models, expectation-maximization

I am new to HMM but I have gone through enough literature. I am working on a project in which I will be predicting rainfall using atmospheric parameters.

I have four observable characteristics of the atmosphere (humidity, temperature, wind, sea level height) for 10 years. I have also rainfall amount data with me.

As per I can understand, for each day a weather state will be specified on the basis of the spatial rainfall. So here goes the question. Lets suppose I have data for 100 days.

Rainfall = { 1,2,3,4... 100}. So if I want to generate weather states what should I do?

Lets suppose

```
temperature = { 30 to 45, some kind of distribution }
humidity = { 25 to 80 }
wind = { 60 to 100 }
sea level height = { 35 to 90 }
```

How to find

- P(X_0) Initial parameter,
- P(X_t|X_t-1) state transition matrix,
- P(Y_t|X_t) dependence of observation on state

Do I need some clustering for generating states?

I am coding it in MATLAB.

You can come with your example or any source which can explain the procedure to implement in program.

Comment: As @nispio pointed out in the answer below, HMMs are fundamentally constructed using discrete-valued state and output variables. You might want to look into [Kalman Filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) ([tutorial](http://bilgin.esme.org/BitsBytes/KalmanFilterforDummies.aspx)), which is the same model but uses continuous-valued states and outputs -- might be a better type of model for your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

An HMM has a discrete number of states, so your first step will be to define your states.  Once you have well-defined states, come up with a numbering scheme for your states and write a function that can accept the data for a given time period, and output the state number that corresponds to that state.

Once you have a function (let's call it `get_state`) that maps data to a state number, you can create your state transition matrix as follows:

```
T = zeros(num_states);
for day = 2:num_days
    s1 = get_state(data(day-1));
    s2 = get_state(data(day));
    T(s1,s2) = T(s1,s2) + 1;
end
```

The `i,j`-th element of the matrix `T` now gives you the transition counts from state `i` to `j`. You can turn this into transition probabilities as follows:

```
M = bsxfun(@rdivide,T+1,sum(T+1,2));
```

The dependence of the observation on the state is harder.  You will have to figure out how you want to turn the observed data into a probability density function or probability mass function.  You can have mutliple observed distributions from a single state instead of combining temperature, humidity, etc., into a single observation.

This is obviously not a full implementation, but hopefully it is enough to give you a starting point.